# Blueimp file upload : my DELETE link doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Here is my form (basic upload) :

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
    <span>Select files...</span>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
</span>
<br>
<div id="files" class="files"></div>
```

Here is my script :

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: 'server/php/',
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').appendTo('#files');
            data.submit();
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').html('<a href="#" class="text-danger delete" data-type="' + file.deleteType + '" data-url="' + file.deleteUrl + '" title="Delete">Delete</a>').appendTo('#files');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

My upload is OK but when I click on the DELETE link, nothing happens. It seems like this link has no effect. Maybe I missed to include something ?

Any idea ?

Comment: what errors do you see in your console ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you haven’t set up an event listener on the link.

```
$('#files').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $link = $(this);

  var req = $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: $link.data('url'),
    type: 'DELETE'
  });

  req.success(function () {
    $link.closet('p').remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: My mistake... You rock !

Comment: Could you please tell me how to remove delete link from response GUI

Answer (score 2):

you might have resolved your problem but just adding my answer for any new solution seeker.

you don't need to make a delete request manually as done by @rglyall, just setup the html structure properly and Jquery-file-upload will take care of it itself.

change

`<a href="#" class="text-danger delete" data-type="' + file.deleteType + '" data-url="' + file.deleteUrl + '" title="Delete">Delete</a>`

to

```
<button class="text-danger delete" data-type="' + file.deleteType + '" data-url="' + file.deleteUrl + '" title="Delete">Delete</button>
```

you need to make sure following things exist to library automatically handle this i.e

1. Html element has to be 'button'.
2. This button has to have a class of 'delete'.
3. This button has to have 'data-type'.
4. This button has to have 'data-url'.